# $q$-Deformed Quillen–Suslin Theorem for the Quantum Vector Spaces?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups, projective-modules

Define **n-quantum vector space** to be the algebra
$$
{\mathbb C}_q^n := \mathbb{C}\left< x_i \mid i =1, \ldots, N\right>/\left<x_i x_j = q x_j x_i \mid i<j\right>.
$$
For $q=1$, we get the usual polynomial ring in $n$-variables, and so, Serre's conjecture (Quillen–Suslin theorem) tells that every finitely generated projective module over ${\mathbb C}_1^n$ is free. How does this work for $q \neq 1$? Is there a $q$-deformed Quillen–Suslin theorem? The not a root of unity case is the most interesting to me.

Comment: Have you checked out Lam's book "Serre's problem on projective modules" (the 2006 edition)? Chapter VIII (New developments since 1977) contains subsections on non-commutative and quantum versions. I do not have my copy handy, so I can not  check right now if your question is answered there...

Comment: Thanks, but I checked the book and it gives a result only when $N=2$.

Comment: See also this remark on PhysicsOverflow to the same questions: http://www.physicsoverflow.org/24083/deformed-quillen-suslin-theorem-the-quantum-vector-spaces?show=24094#a24094

Answer (score 1):

See extensive 1998 survey

[Uspekhi Mat. Nauk, 1998,   Volume 53,  Issue 4(322),

Serre's quantum problem 
V. A. Artamonov](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=rm&paperid=56&option_lang=eng)

Russian pdf is available for free from that page.
See also other papers by the author.

At the bottom of second page he writes (translated from Russian):

**F.g. projective modules of sufficiently HIGH RANK are free,** 
at least at two cases: (1) $q_{ij}$ are roots of unity (2) $q_{ij}$ are at general position.

Comment: This result is also mentioned in Lam's book on Serre's problem, in section VIII.11 (it came up in the comments to the question)